# validating request through requestValidationMode="4.0" its working some Apis not all

Tags: scripting

I have updated the **requestValidationMode** in my **web.config** file from **"2.0"** to **"4.0"** to enhance security in my API. However, I've noticed that even with this configuration, the API still allows the input alert('Tanveer') to be saved in the database. How can I ensure that request validation configured with **requestValidationMode="4.0"** effectively blocks such potentially harmful data from being saved?

I've tried **requestValidationMode="4.0" ** in my  **web.config** file to enhance security,  I 've noticed it works Some APIs not others. How can I ensure that request validation consistently enforced All APIs?.